# How to parse csv file and keep the correct type in python?

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file that has these types as the columns:

```
float64 | float64 | int64 | object
```

and I want to create a csv file by using the values in the above csv file, which I tried with

```
 # get headers
 with open(filename, "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for headers in reader:
        break

# read CSV to get old rows
with open(filename, "r") as f:
    readCSV = list(csv.reader(f, delimiter=","))

# add rows to CSV   
for i in range (0,4)
    for j in range (1, 100)
with open(outputfile, "a", newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=headers)
    writer.writerow([(readCSV[i*100 + j][0] + 86400), \
                     readCSV[i*100 + j][1], \
                     readCSV[i*100 + j][2], \
                     readCSV[i*100 + j][3]])
```

Basically I want to make a new file that has 5 copies of the original 100 rows in the original file, but with the first float64 value incremented more each loop. But the `csv.reader` returns a string type so I can't increment the value and write it as a float 64.

I did change the values for this question as the original code had a bit more elongated code and a huge amount of rows, but I think I got the idea across.

If the object type cannot be kept which i have doubts that ti can, then it is not critical for the new csv file to have that column. The float64 and int64 columns are however.

Comment: You might want to look into `pandas` a module that handles tabular data, this would then be fairly trivial.

Comment: Turn the strings into floats or ints before doing the math: ... `float(col1)`, `int(col3)`.

Comment: Use Pandas. It will make your life much easier. You can read the csv file in one shot by using read_csv(filename). After you manipulate the data as you like, you can simply call to_csv() to write the data to CSV file. No need to write so many lines of code.

Comment: If your `object` column is a custom class and not one of the built-in types, you will need to do some sort of serialization, like saving your object to `json`. Even pandas won't be able to save you from having to write something that will read the data from the file and know how to create your desired object from it. If you have control of your data before it gets into the csv format, I would recommend looking into [pickles](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html). Dataframes in pandas also have a to/from pickle method.

Comment: `csv` files are text files, so the row and the fields in each row are strings — so in that context your question doesn't make much sense.